# Setter inside Rails.application.configure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In a Rails4 project I am working on,

inside the development.rb file (and in the others enviroments),
inside the configure block:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ...
  config.foo = 'foo'
end
```

I can use whatever setter I want, like config.**foo=**

(I suppose some dynamic code under the hood)

what's the purpouse of that and how does it work ? I did't not find any documentation about it.

Thanks for any help to understant it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code in [rails/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/463b5d7581ee16bfaddf34ca349b7d1b5878097c/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L9-L19) file on the rails code base sets what the valid config options are:

```
attr_accessor :allow_concurrency, :asset_host, :assets, :autoflush_log,
              :cache_classes, :cache_store, :consider_all_requests_local, :console,
              :eager_load, :exceptions_app, :file_watcher, :filter_parameters,
              :force_ssl, :helpers_paths, :logger, :log_formatter, :log_tags,
              :railties_order, :relative_url_root, :secret_key_base, :secret_token                    :serve_static_files, :ssl_options, :static_cache_control, :session_options,
              :time_zone, :reload_classes_only_on_change,
              :beginning_of_week, :filter_redirect, :x

attr_writer :log_level
attr_reader :encoding
```

Rails uses any of the settings mentioned above, and simply ignores the rest.

The `dynamic code under the hood` is also in the [same file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/463b5d7581ee16bfaddf34ca349b7d1b5878097c/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L166-L174)

```
      def method_missing(method, *args)
        if method =~ /=$/
          @configurations[$`.to_sym] = args.first
        else
          @configurations.fetch(method) {
            @configurations[method] = ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new
          }
        end
      end
```